# How to add PictureCallback on ZXing and journeyapps?

Tags: android, android-camera, qr-code, zxing, barcode-scanner

So I have been using the library from ZXing and the one from journeyapps:
https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded

I need to get the full image instead of the cropped bitmap from BarcodeResult.getBitmap(). The only solution I can come up with is to hook up an android.hardware.camera.PictureCallback to a camera instance. But the opened Camera by these libraries are declared private, thus, I cannot have access to them.